# Use Selenium to click on items in a UL one by one and scrape some information

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

i'm just practicing scraping with selenium

[image: inspect element image]

What i would like to do is go through each item in the unordered list

[image: href]

get every list item

```
 wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='main_content']/ul" )))
ul_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='main_content']/ul")

all_li_element = ul_element.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li")
```

then after i got the list items to go to each one and scrape some data

is there a better way because the way i'm thinking about it, it will turn into a nested list

Answer (score 0):

Probably this can be done much faster, without opening all those links, but not with Selenium. Selenium imitates human GUI actions, so as a human do scrape all that data you do need to open all those links and read the data on the opened pages. However this can be done much clearer and faster via API calls or with Beautifulsoup etc. But again, these are not Selenium UI approaches.

Answer (score 0):

> the way i'm thinking about it, it will turn into a nested list

unless you concatenate all details into one string [which I would *not* advise], or you only need one detail, there will have to be *some* nesting to whatever data structure you have the output as; since you a set of details for a list of items, there will have to be at least one level of nesting [list of items -> set of details]

However, it's not that complicated - you can just make a list of dictionaries with the details you want from each card [including, and especially, the link], and then go through that list of dictionaries and add to each dictionary by going to the link and scraping the rest of the info.

---

First, I like to separate out the actual detail-extraction into a function that I can reuse.

<sub>[This is a simplified version of another function I often use when scraping; if interested, [check out the full version](https://pastebin.com/BpjZSQPi).]</sub>

```py
def extractAttr(elem, sel, attr, defVal=None):
    e = elem.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, sel)
    aVal = e[0].get_attribute(attr) if e else None
    return defVal if aVal is None else aVal
```

and also prepare most of the inputs the function will need:

```py
liSels = [ # selectors for the list items
    ('name', 'span[itemprop="name"]', 'innerText'),
    ('link', 'a[itemprop="url"][href]', 'href'),
    ('imgUrl', 'img[itemprop="photo"][src]', 'src')
]
pgSels = [ # selectors for the individual pages
    ('description', 'p.description', 'innerText'),
    ('moreInfo', 'li.large-margin-bottom > h3 + ul', 'innerText')
]
```

(You can add or remove from `liSels` and `pgSels` according to whatever details you need/want. Also, I'm using CSS selectors due to personal preference; you can swap them out for their XPath equivalents if you're more comfortable with that - just make sure to adjust the function to match.)

---

Now that the function and selectors are ready, you can just get to going through the pages to build that list of dictionaries

```py
# driver = webdriver.Chrome()
# wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
rootUrl = 'https://www.crunchyroll.com'
cardSel = '#main_content > ul > li'

driver.get(f'{rootUrl}/comics/manga')
wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, cardSel)))

cards = [{
    k: extractAttr(c, s, a) for k, s, a in liSels
} for c in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, cardSel)]
for i, c in enumerate(cards):
    driver.get(c['link'])
    for k, s, a in pgSels:
        cards[i][k] = extractAttr(driver, s, a)

# driver.quit()
```

and `cards[:5]` will look something like      <sub>**(only 5 of 50 dictionaries are included below)**</sub>

```py
[
 {'name': 'Genshin Impact', 'link': 'https://www.crunchyroll.com/comics/manga/genshin-impact/volumes', 'imgUrl': 'https://api-manga.crunchyroll.com/i/croll_manga/9e6d8c402f2916bd093fc7a1524265ca_1544713688_large.jpg', 'description': 'Aeons ago, the elder elemental gods granted civilization to the human race, but the world soon splintered as corruption and greed grew without check. Can the forces holding this world together be balanced against human desires, or is everything ultimately doomed to end in destruction? http://genshin.mihoyo.com/', 'moreInfo': 'Publisher: miHoYo Limited\nFirst Published:\nAuthor: miHoYo\nArtist: miHoYo\nCopyright: © 2017-2018 miHoYo Limited ALL RIGHTS RESERVED'} ,
 {'name': 'Inside Mari', 'link': 'https://www.crunchyroll.com/comics/manga/inside-mari/volumes', 'imgUrl': 'https://api-manga.crunchyroll.com/i/croll_manga/70d74c2842e6ebed097c8309889c67e8_1389837055_large.jpg', 'description': 'A young man is a shut-in, with nothing to do but kill time. The sole pleasure in his life is following home an angelic high school girl he sees every day in a convenience store. Today, like any other day, he follows her, but… Shuzo Oshimi, the creator of Drifting Net Café and Flowers of Evil, continues to open hidden doors of the heart in this monthly serialized story!', 'moreInfo': 'Publisher: Futabasha\nFirst Published:\nAuthor:\nArtist: Shuzo Oshimi\nCopyright: ©Shuzo Oshimi/FUTABASHA PUBLISHERS LTD.\nTranslator: Sheldon Drzka\nEditor: Emily Martha Sorensen\nLetterer: Carl Vanstiphout'} ,
 {'name': 'To Your Eternity', 'link': 'https://www.crunchyroll.com/comics/manga/to-your-eternity/volumes', 'imgUrl': 'https://api-manga.crunchyroll.com/i/croll_manga/c49832d6c4e25d693e6b88b0328e70a5_1519720335_large.jpg', 'description': 'A new manga from the creator of the acclaimed A Silent Voice, featuring intimate, emotional drama and an epic story spanning time and space, To Your Eternity is a totally unique and moving manga about death, life, reincarnation, and the nature of love. A lonely boy wandering the Arctic regions of North America meets a wolf, and the two become fast friends, depending on each other to survive the harsh environment. But the boy has a history, and the wolf is more than meets the eye as well …', 'moreInfo': 'Publisher: Kodansha\nFirst Published:\nAuthor:\nArtist:\nCopyright: Based on the manga "Fumetsu no Anata he" by Yoshitoki Oima originally serialized in the Weekly Shonen magazine published by KODANSHA LTD. To Your Eternity copyright © Yoshitoki Oima／KODANSHA LTD. English translation copyright © Yoshitoki Oima／KODANSHA LTD. All rights reserved.\nTranslator: Steven LeCroy\nEditor: Alexandra Swanson\nLetterer: Darren Smith'} ,
 {'name': 'Sun-Ken Rock', 'link': 'https://www.crunchyroll.com/comics/manga/sun-ken-rock/volumes', 'imgUrl': 'https://api-manga.crunchyroll.com/i/croll_manga/368cba1b39ae46b3435e6ac1d4f5987e_1391991276_large.jpg', 'description': 'Ken left Japan, pursuing the woman he loves to Korea. However, while she became a policewoman, Ken somehow wound up in a gang, even becoming their boss! The man who came from Japan now rises in Korea. It\'s Korean "Rock-Action" with a powerful punch!', 'moreInfo': 'Publisher: Shonen Gahosha\nFirst Published:\nAuthor:\nArtist: Boichi\nCopyright: ©BOICHI/Shonen-gahosha Co., Ltd.'} ,
 {'name': 'Fire Force', 'link': 'https://www.crunchyroll.com/comics/manga/fire-force/volumes', 'imgUrl': 'https://api-manga.crunchyroll.com/i/croll_manga/83fa13859c8baee6f20708b5d4bd5c35_1640071967_large.jpg', 'description': 'A new action fantasy set in a steampunk Tokyo from the creator of the smash-hit Soul Eater!The city of Tokyo is plagued by a deadly phenomenon: spontaneous human combustion! Luckily, a special team is there to quench the inferno: The Fire Force! The fire soldiers at Special Fire Cathedral 8 are about to get a unique addition. Enter Shinra, a boy who possesses the power to run at the speed of a rocket, leaving behind the famous “devil’s footprints” (and destroying his shoes in the process). ... more', 'moreInfo': 'Publisher: Kodansha\nFirst Published:\nAuthor: Atsushi Ohkubo\nArtist: Atsushi Ohkubo\nCopyright: Based on the manga "En\'en no Shōbōtai" by Atsushi Ohkubo originally serialized in the weekly Shonen Magazine published by KODANSHA LTD. Fire Force copyright © Atsushi Ohkubo／KODANSHA LTD. English translation copyright © Atsushi Ohkubo／KODANSHA LTD. All rights reserved.'} ,
]
```

---

At this point, it would be very easy to save or view this with something like [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)

```py
# import pandas
pandas.DataFrame(cards).to_csv('crunchyCards.csv', index=False)
```

would produce a spreadsheet like
[image: crunchyCards.csv]